# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Error

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a problem.

```
public class Deck {
    //deck contents returns every card in the deck

    String[] suits = {"Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
    String[] ranks = {"Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
                      "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    int[] values = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10,11};

    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();

    ArrayList<Card> cardsDealt = new ArrayList<Card>(); //unused here

            Random rand = new Random(); //unused here

    public Deck(){
            for(int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++){
                for(int k = 0; i < ranks.length; k++){
                        deck.add(new Card(suits[i], ranks[k], values[k]));          
                } 
            }
        }
```

I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException Error. My task is to create a Deck object which will then add 52 Card Objects into an ArrayList called deck. I wrote the for loops to create each of the possible 52 cards in a card deck. What is the error?

Comment: `i < ranks.length` isn't what you intended for the loop bound.

Comment: what would i used instead?

Comment: Look at the loop carefully. Look at the variable it's initializing and incrementing, then look at the variable you're checking.

Comment: Also i forgot to mention, the parameter list for a Card object is a String suit, String rank, and an int value.

Comment: Doesn't really matter here. Look at your second loop again!

Comment: i should be k in your second loop

Comment: OHH fail lol I got the error. Thanks Jon Skeet!

Comment: `k < ranks.length` for second loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++){
    for(int k = 0; i < ranks.length; k++){
                   ^
        deck.add(new Card(suits[i], ranks[k], values[k]));          
    } 
}
```

it's not `i < ranks.length` but `k < ranks.length` !

```
for(int i = 0; i < suits.length; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < ranks.length; k++){
        deck.add(new Card(suits[i], ranks[k], values[k]));          
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed out of that lol

Comment: @noobforce no problem it happend sometimes ;) don't forget to put as corrected !

Comment: yes, i need to wait 10 min tho :p

Answer (score 1):

Swap the `i` for `k` in here:

```
for(int k = 0; i < ranks.length; k++){
```

i.e.

```
for(int k = 0; k < ranks.length; k++){
```

You're constantly checking whether `i` is less than `ranks.length` to terminate the loop (which in this inner loop, it always will be...), so `k` continues to get incremented beyond `ranks.length`, hence the error once you attempt to access suits[13].